# How upgrade google + button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-plus

I am beginner web programmer - please help me.

I have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js"></script>
            <g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>
```

I should upgrade him to asynchronous snippet: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/07/1-button-now-faster.html

My problem I don't which image size to choose in google config tool that will be same size as
`<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>` that I already have in the website.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The tool says `<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>`.

Comment: I think it's the one that's called "tall".

Comment: I find answer:should choose tall in config tool thanks for all!

Comment: +1 For solving this difficult problem by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you're getting the correct idea. You're not changing the button, but instead the way the script behaves. Just keep your `<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>` and change the script accordingly

Comment: can I include script tag inside div or it should be ouside divs? - directly in body?

Comment: before your closing body-tag (looks like this: `</body>`) simply add the script code inside a script tag: `<script type="text/javascript">//Script Code goes here</script>`

Answer (score 2):

Choose "Tall"

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone size="tall"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this tag after the last plusone tag -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

For Advacned information see **+1 tag parameters** section here: http://code.google.com/apis/+1button/